# Azure DevOps query to see if a tag was ever associated with a Work Item

Tags: azure-devops

Tags are sometimes deleted when they shouldn't be. Is there a way to query to see when a Work Item had it's tags changed?

'Changed Tags' appears in 'History', but I don't see an option to query that specifically.

Comment: Any updates? Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

No such a work item query to check that. However, we can call the [Revisions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API to check the history.

Below PowerShell script for your reference. In this example, we check if a tag named "`Tag01`" was ever added to a particular work item. If there is a response value, it means that the tag has been used before, otherwise the tag had not been used on the work item.

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}",
   [string]$project = "Test0924",
   [string]$wi = 2328,
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$baseUrl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($wi)/revisions?api-version=5.0"                   
$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
$revisions = $response.value | where({$_.fields.'System.Tags' -like 'Tag01*'}) # Set the filter here, in this example check if a tag named "Tag01" ever used on this work item. 

# Get work item history- revisions

$witrevisions = @()

foreach($revision in $revisions){

       $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WorkItemID" = $wi
          "Revision" = $revision.rev 
          "WorkItemType" = $revision.fields.'System.WorkItemType'           
          "AreaPath" = $revision.fields.'System.AreaPath'
          "TeamProject" = $revision.fields.'System.TeamProject'
          "IterationPath" = $revision.fields.'System.IterationPath'
          "ChangedBy" = $revision.fields.'System.ChangedBy'.displayName
          "SystemState" = $revision.fields.'System.State'
          "StateChangeDate" = $revision.fields.'System.ChangedDate'
          "SystemTags" = $revision.fields.'System.Tags'
              } 
       
       $witrevisions += $customObject          
}
       
$witrevisions | Select-Object `
                WorkItemID,
                Revision,
                WorkItemType,
                AreaPath,
                TeamProject, 
                IterationPath,
                ChangedBy, 
                SystemState,
                StateChangeDate,
                SystemTags
```

[image]